# Navigation drawer is not closing while navigation item is selected

Tags: android, listview, navigation-drawer

I am creating a navigation drawer. the drawer is not closing while i select the list item in the navigation drawer. Here is my code

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    <!-- This DrawerLayout has two children at the root  -->


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- This LinearLayout represents the contents of the screen  -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <!-- The main content view where fragments are loaded -->
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/flContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listViewNavDrawer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_weight="40" 
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice" 
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            tools:context=".NavigationDrawerFragment"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

what is the problem with that ? While using NavigationView instead of ListView there is no problem. But I need a ListView for my app. what should I do?

Comment: Call `DrawerLayout#closeDrawer()` after a list item click. It won't close itself automatically.

Comment: thank you . But why is it won't close automatically? It is closing automatically , while using NavigationView . Can you explain the reson?

Comment: `NavigationView` is written to integrate with `DrawerLayout` like that. A plain, old `ListView` doesn't have that functionality.

Comment: thank you . and that worked. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call a method to close the active drawer, like [DrawerLayout.closeDrawers()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#closeDrawers()).

Comment: But why is it won't close automatically? It is closing automatically , while using NavigationView . Can you explain the reason?